# Python - queue.clear() doesn't works

Tags: python, queue, pyserial, modem

Hello I write an application for modem ST75-80. My problem is while I click on "Reset" button in my app first time I receive good frames. When i click more than one time "Reset" button queue doesn't clear and values append to already index.

`ser` is a variable which operate on pySerial library

```
global ser
ser = serial.Serial()
global q
q = queue.Queue()

def serveException():
        try:
            time.sleep(0.05)
            t2 = Thread(target=receiveData, args=())
            if(t2.isAlive()==False):
                t2.start()
        except:
            print("Nie moze wystartowac watek")    

def receiveData():
    global ser
    global q
    while(True):
        if(ser.isOpen() == True):
            if(ser.inWaiting()):
                s = ser.read()
                for i in s:
                    q.put(i)
                while not q.empty():
                    print(hex(q.get()))
                    q.queue.clear()

def sendReset():
    try:
        tablicaHEX = bytes([0x02, 0x00, 0x3C, 0x3C, 0x00])
        ser.setRTS(True)
        ser.setDTR(True)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        ser.write(bytes(tablicaHEX))
        ser.setRTS(False)
        ser.setDTR(True)
        serveException()
    except:
        print("nie")

def createResetButton():
     buttonReset = Button(text = "Reset", command=sendReset)
     buttonReset.grid(row=2, column = 2)

def createFrame():
    mainFrame = tkinter.Tk()
    mainFrame.geometry('300x200')
    createLabel()
    createDataList()
    listOfComPorts(mainFrame)
    createConnectButton()
    createResetButton()
    mainFrame.mainloop()

def main():
    createFrame()
    ser.close
```

My question is: What can i do? I would receive the same data as at first time:

Output:

```
0x3f
0x9
0x6
```

itd itd. 
Next Click

```
0x3f0x9

0x60x2
```

Comment: The `global` statement is only needed in *functions*, and only to override the normal assumption that a name is local. You are never assigning to the `ser` or  `q` names directly, in any of your functions, so you can remove those statements entirely. They make no difference to your code here.

Comment: You need to ensure thread-safety: `with q.mutex: q.queue.clear()`, you probably have a race condition. See [Clear all items from the queue](//stackoverflow.com/q/6517953)

Comment: But why are you even putting data into a queue then immediately clearing it from that queue in the same thread? Why bother with a queue *at all*?

Comment: Yeah i saw that now. How can i repair it ?

Comment: This thrad in infinity loop. How can i stop thread when i click on button ?

Comment: [How to close a thread from within?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4541190)

Comment: [Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/323972)

Comment: And more; the answers are usually already here.